# Why are independent process taking longer as time goes on?

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008

I have created my own Job Manager app.

This run multiple copies of my worker app on a dedicated server. I run about 3000 worker processes (Jobs) in batches of 50 on my 30 core machine. Each job does a similar amount of work. Reads data from cache on SSD disk, writes information at milestones on harddrive and Sql database.

Network traffic is low, Disk usage is low, SqlServer activity is low, memory remains constant at around 60% of my 120G.

Each batch of jobs starts to take longer. Initially, the first few hundred jobs each make good use of CPU, but then CPU usage starts to go down (show 0 a lot) and time of job starts increasing. I don't understand why this is, given that my Resource Manager is not show anything maxed out.

What might be happening here?

Each Worker Process (Job) is a completely indepedently started instance of my exe. So I don't think it can be a memory leakage thing.

I can't profile - as profile on a single run of an instance of exe shows it is running fast!

Comment: Sounds like contention on some resource, but without code that's just a wild guess.  Maybe you can post code or something that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Problem is that it is a very big app. Wouldn't I see contention in Resource Manager though?

Comment: It really depends on what your job is doing and how it's doing it.  I could code something very slow that uses little CPU and resources simply by abusing a `Mutex`.  In your case I'm wondering if the bottleneck is the database or file system.  Have you tried profiling SQL Server?  There is a huge difference between time measuring metrics.  CPU time and _wall clock_ time, for example, are totally different measures.

Comment: While it does not sound like the usual invalid questions on the topic of speed, I do feel the speed rant might help you: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @Zer0 "I could code something very slow that uses little CPU and resources simply by abusing a Mutex." Or even simpler `Thread.Sleep(10000);` Takes 10 seconds, at near 0 consumption of CPU. | I agree there are too many uncertains in the existing description to give anything but wild guesses.